# openid.ui.mode using rails' openid_authentication plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid

I'm using the [openid_authentication](https://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication) plugin to login my users with openid.

On some pages (the one designed for mobile apps), I'd like to provide the `openid.ui.mode = "popup"` option so that the provider would display a lighter version of the login page.

Though, it appears the rack-openid gem (on which openid_authentication relies) filters the parameters provided, not allowing anything else than fields.

So doing the following :

```
authenticate_with_open_id(nil, {'openid.ui.mode' => 'popup'}) do |result|
```

Does not work.

Comment: Is there no prefix that it will not filter?  like xopenid. or something?  If reading through the docs/source show that you cannot get extra data through you could try using a cookie I guess.  Or switch libraries.  Or patch the library.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
authenticate_with_open_id( nil, {'optional' => {'openid.ui.mode' => 'popup'}})...
```

If that doesn't work, you can try another OpenID plugin with more features:

- https://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable
- https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work. I know we should use omniauth. But it's not currently a priority.